# solidify modifier adding non uniform thickness to the mesh

Tags: modifiers

I have a simple table without any thickness, I started with a cube and deleted 3 of the faces, applied a subdivision surface modifier and did a few loop cuts to achieve this shape shown here:
[image: table no thickness]

however when I try to add a solidify modifier to it, the thickness is not evenly distributed so the sides are thicker than the middle and the mesh also gets distorted shown here:
[image: table with thickness]

I want the table to have a uniform thickness just like in real life, and get rid of the weird distortion, I am relatively new to blender and this might seem obvious but any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: maybe try to apply the scale of your object: in Edit mode, ctrl A > Scale, because you may have made scale in Object mode instead of Edit mode. There also might be a topology problem as your object looks weird (artifacts). Also, click on the Even Thickness option of the modifier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have scaled your object in *Object* mode rather than *Edit* mode. If you do it in *Object* mode, Blender still considers the original size of the object when you'll assign it a *Solidify* modifier.

So you need to select your object and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Scale*, so that now the scale you've made is applied to the mesh itself and not only to the object.

Also, enable the *Even Thickness* of the modifier, it could prevent some other distorsions.

And at last, your object mesh must be a little bit messy because you have strange artifacts, try to make a clean topology.

[image]