# How to evenly add thickness to faces in blender

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, faces, solidify-modifier

I'm somewhat new to blender. I have a box with one of its faces being deleted. I'm trying to add a thickness of 2cm to all remaining faces; however, all faces will not be extruded by 2cm.
[image]

As can be seen, the top face has become thicker than the side faces.

Comment: Apply the scale to your object in Object mode with Ctrl-A > Scale and try again.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116569/solidify-modifier-adding-non-uniform-thickness-to-the-mesh/